# Как внедрить репозиторий в test-dir c SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Я настроил итеграционный тест в **мультимодульном** проекте, в модуле **web**, в котором находится точка входа...

- src/test/java/com/web/service/read/company/CompanyReadServiceTest.java

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = WebSpringBootJarApplication.class )
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = NONE)
@Sql({
        "classpath:sql/create_sequence_different_types.sql",
        "classpath:sql/create-company.sql",
        "classpath:sql/insert_company.sql"
})
@TestPropertySource(
        locations = "classpath:application-integration-test.properties")
public class CompanyReadServiceTest {


    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CompanyReadServiceTest.class);

    private static String NAME_METHOD_READ_BY_NAME_BOOLEAN = "isByName";

    @Autowired
    private CompanyReadService companyReadService;

    @Autowired
    private CompanyReadRepositoryTest companyReadRepositoryTest;


    @Test
    public void getById() {

...
```

- src/test/java/com/web/dao/repository/company/CompanyReadRepositoryTest.java

```java
public interface CompanyReadRepositoryTest extends CrudRepository<Company, Long> {

    String nameTable = "company";
    String lastEntryQueryFor =
            "select * from (select t.* from " + nameTable + " t order by 1 desc) where rownum = 1";

    @Query(value =lastEntryQueryFor, nativeQuery = true)
    Optional<Company> getLastEntry();
}
```

Но получаю ошибку, в которой сообщается что нет возможности создать и внедрить такой комонент

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'com.web.service.read.company.CompanyReadServiceTest': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'companyReadRepositoryTest'; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'com.web.dao.repository.company.CompanyReadRepositoryTest' available:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
>   Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Кто знает в чем здесь дело и как это можно исправить ?

Answer (score 0):

**Решение**

Вам нужно переместить **dao.repository** в корень test-dir. Это директория com.

src/test/java/com/dao/repository

Вы повторяете расположение репозиториев в модуле dao-module.

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Sql({
        "classpath:sql/create_sequence_different_types.sql",
        "classpath:sql/create-company.sql",
        "classpath:sql/insert_company.sql"
})
@TestPropertySource(
        locations = "classpath:application-integration-test.properties")
public class CompanyReadServiceTest {
...
```